# Add new line to the value inside a variable for table data in reportlab

Tags: python, tkinter, reportlab

So this is my two sample variable

```
a = '$2000'
b = '$1000'
```

Is it possible to add these two variables inside another variable with new line.
I tried this following code but this didn't worked:

```
c = a + '\n' + b
```

I want new line because I want to use it inside a table column.

This is my sample code of what I'm trying.

```
tabledata = [ 
['sample1'],
[verticalText (c)]  # I want to make changes here so that $1000 appears after $2000 but in same column
]
```

I'm using reportlab table here. Any idea how to break line?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [reportlab userguide](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf) on page 88 (Version 3.5.36): There is an example of a table cell with linebreaks.
Addressing your problem:

```
tabledata = [["sample1"],
             [f"{a}\n{b}"]]
```